# left and right keydown event for changing pics with cat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simply I have a div with `data-next`, `data-prev`, `data-cat` attr.

And here is the js so far..

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

    var prev = $("#myDiv").attr('data-prev'),
        cat = $("#myDiv").attr('data-cat'),
        next = $("#myDiv").attr('data-next');

    switch (event.keyCode) {

        case 37:
            if (prev >= 1) {
                window.location = "http://site.com/picture/" + prev;
            }
            break;

        case 39:
            if (next > 1) {
                window.location = "http://site.com/picture/" + next;
            }
            break;
    }
});​
```

The code is working but only for **left** and **right** action. For the cat i think to do it like so , but I think is wrong and there is better way to do it !

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

    var prev = $("#myDiv").attr('data-prev'),
        cat = $("#myDiv").attr('data-cat'),
        next = $("#myDiv").attr('data-next');

    if (cat) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {

        case 37:
            if (prev >= 1) {
                window.location = "http://site.com/picture/" + prev;
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            if (next > 1) {
                window.location = "http://site.com/picture/" + next;
            }
            break;

        }
    }
    else {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            // but i dont how to insert the cat var the link have to be cat/{n}/picture/{n}
        case 37:
            if (prev >= 1) {
                window.location = "http://site.com/picture/" + prev;
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            if (next > 1) {
                window.location = "http://site.com/picture/" + next;
            }
            break;

        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Could you paste your HTML, maybe it'll help ? Thanks.

Comment: Its a simple div <div id="myDiv" data-next="5" data-prev="3" data-cat="{nothing or a number}"> and i'm not sure how to implement the js when there is a cat or not

Comment: So you want cat/{n}/picture/{n} ? What about "http:// site.com/cat/"+ cat +"/picture/" + next;

Comment: Yes thanks for the url @mdi :) but is the hole code good .. i mean there must be something to improve. I'm not that good in js thats why i'm asking

Comment: Oh, now I understand, you want to know how it could be done better. Maybe you could use only one data-cat and compute next and prev. I'll look at it later this afternoon.

Comment: So, I have some questions : are your cats numbers linear ? (1,2,3,4,5,etc.) Why do you want to test for (cat), do you have any case where (cat) does not exist ?

Comment: yes the cat is numbers linear from 1 to 9 and yes i have to two pages. One that shows all pics and base ot the current pic ID i get the next and prev pics. In the second page like /cat/6/picture/456 i want to switch between pics from that cat! And yes if the user is in page one the cat id /data-cat will be empty. Right now everything is working bur maybe can be done better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(lots of explanations in comments)

So, I wondered why you used window.location : it makes an useless refresh of the page.

I made a small script, very basic, which changes the img src on keypress. You may have to tweak it (I used cats from placekitten.com), but i keeps your image numbering. I tried to keep it simple and easy to understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/teVPD/11/

Lots of functionality could be added (animations, cat preloading), but it's a good start to enhance your car slider.

Have a look, and if you have any question don't hesitate to ask'em.

Comment: Your script is pretty good (y). I use window.location because I want to reload the page since user can add comments and will show the comments so far for the current pic. In the future they will be added more categories.I will tweak it a little bit :) Thanks alot @mdi